# Subsetting a factor on amount of observations in R

Tags: r

So i have this dataset

```
str(pcol)
'data.frame':   3130486 obs. of  20 variables:
$ body     : Factor w/ 1623190 levels "","' i need to... '",..: 76837  ...
$ author   : Factor w/ 18164 levels "--Kai--","--sunshine--",..: 11455 6643 8117 832 ...
$ ups      : int  2 7 1 1 1 1 2 4 2 1 ...
....
```

Making a table shows the following:

```
table(pcol$author):
AuthornameX   AuthornameY   AuthornameZ ...
148           87            102

 'table' int [1:18164(1d)] 129 5 152 67 18 25 58 319 44 204 ...
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
..$ : chr [1:18164] "--Kai--" "--sunshine--" "-0---0-" "-73-" ...
```

So now i want to create a new dataset with just authors who are in the dataset more than 100 times.

**I tried the following:**

```
x <- subset(pcol, length(pcol$author) > 100 )
'table' int [1:2634(1d)] 129 152 319 204 157 177 198 106 144 437 ...
 attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
..$ : chr [1:2634] "--Kai--" "-0---0-" "-Lolrax-" "-PTM-" ...
```

This way i limited the authors, who have numbers over 100. But now I have the problem of how to substract these authors from the original dataset.

I tried this:

```
> y <- subset(pcol, pcol$authors == x)
```

But that leaves me with a blank dataframe with 0 observations.

**So: how do i change the original dataset to a new one, only with authors, who appear over 100 times?**

[My question is similar to this one, so potentially a duplicate.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555858/subsetting-based-on-number-of-observations-in-a-factor-variable) Althought the question was answered, I was not able to transfer the solution there to my problem. That is why I pose my question.

[Here is a 10.000 rows sample of my data set](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rjplcbbjpm7br5w/pcol1.csv?dl=0)

Comment: Aggregate and add new column that shows the count per Author, then use subset on that column. Also add [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Try `y <- subset(pcol, pcol$authors %in% x)`.

Comment: or with `library(dplyr) ; pcol %>% group_by(author) %>% filter(n() > 100)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count rows for selected column values and remove rows based on count in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412337/count-rows-for-selected-column-values-and-remove-rows-based-on-count-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `data.table` package one gets

```
require(data.table)
setDT(pcol)
```

Find the authors with more than 100 occurrences

```
author_sel <- pcol[, .N, by = .(author)][N > 100]
pcol[author %in% author_sel$author]
```

Answer (score 1):

A base solution could be

```
subset(pcol, author %in% names(which(table(pcol$author)>100)))
```

Perhaps you should consider learning dplyr. The dplyr solution is easier to read and faster to run on your computer.

Comment: I added a sample data set. 

I tried your command lines, but alas there were plenty of authors with less than 100 appearances. Maybe the sample dataset gives you a better understanding of what i want to know

Comment: Did this fix your issue?

Comment: Alas it did not. I used stefan8888´s proposal. But anyway, thank you for your help!

Comment: I fixed it right when you made your first comment. nbd, @stefan8888 had a good solution.

Comment: Ah ok. I did not notice that. I just tried your command, and it worked as well. Thank you!